# Adding INNER JOIN with has_many association in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, associations

I have association in rails 3.1

```
has_many :likes, :dependent => :destroy
```

I wanted to add a join with a condition in the above association

```
likes = user.likes.joins('INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = likes.likable_id and likes.likable_type = "Post"').where("posts.is_published", true)
```

So instead of using user.likes.joins(). I only wanted to use user.likes. Scope is also one option but is it possible to add that in association.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, conditions: {"likes.likable_type = 'Post'", "posts.is_published IS true"}, dependent: :destroy
end
```